# Resource not found due to misconfiguration

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat7, web.xml

I am developing a Web application based on Tomcat 7, and bumped in a situation where I have no clue what and why is happening. After typing my login credentials in JSP page below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Login</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="form">
                <form method=POST name=login_form action=Login>
                    Usuário: <input type=text name=username> <br/>
                    Senha: <input type=password name=password> <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
                    <span class="error">${error}</span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I receive the following message, regardless if I entered the right or wrong credentials:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /WebApp/Login

type Status report

message /WebApp/Login

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

The implementation for the method doPost of the servlet class is the following:

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");

Date data_login = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
java.sql.Timestamp nova_data = new java.sql.Timestamp(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
nova_data.setDate(data_login.getDay());
nova_data.setMonth(data_login.getMonth());
nova_data.setYear(data_login.getYear());
nova_data.setHours(data_login.getHours());
nova_data.setMinutes(data_login.getMinutes());
nova_data.setSeconds(nova_data.getSeconds());

DataHelper dhelper = new DataHelper();

try {
    System.out.println("Registrando login...");
    user temp = dhelper.doProcessaLogin(username, password);

    if (temp != null) {
        String fname = temp.getFirstName();
        String lname = temp.getLastName();
        int id = temp.getId();

        System.out.println("Dados corretos");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", fname+" "+lname);
        dhelper.doRegistraSessao(fname, lname, nova_data, id);
        Cookie ck = new Cookie("User",fname+" "+lname);
        ck.setMaxAge(7);
        response.addCookie(ck);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/menu.jsp")
          .forward(request,response);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Dados incorretos");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("erro", 
          "Não foi possivel efetuar o login");
        System.out.println("Direcionando de volta para a pagina de login");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/login").forward(request, response);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have an implementation for a method doGet too:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

my web.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.webapp.servlet.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I really don't know the reason the system is looking for `/WebApp/Login` instead of `/WebApp/login`, which is what was declared in the `web.xml`. Someone can see any problem with the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `action=Login` by `action=login` (lowercase L) in your JSP page. Tomcat is case sensitive and you declared the URL pattern for the servlet mapping as "/login". If it still doesn't work, try with `action=/login`.

Comment: I solve the problem, and ended in another. I replaced the command action=Login br action=/WebApp/Login and it works, but now I have a infine loop, probably caused by line (I think): request.getRequestDispatcher("/login").forward(request, response); I am trying discover now the right choice to replace "/login" in that command.

Comment: ok, that last problem was solved too. I change "/login" by "/index.jsp" and works fine. I will try now find a way to redirect to login page (displaying an error message) after a unsuccessful try.

Comment: thanks for all you guys who give atention to my problem. I hope be able to retribute the help someday.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your form page. See where it says `action=Login` (you should use quotes, by the way, both for readability and for safety)? That's telling the Web browser that the URL it should submit to is `Login` relative to the page it's already on, which is probably `/WebApp/index.jsp`. Fix that `form` tag.

Comment: After your suggestion, I did that change in the form, but still happening the same error.

Comment: Please update the code in your post. Make sure that you do a complete restart of your container (including re-exporting the `war` if you're running it standalone) and doing a hard refresh from your browser. Use your browser's source view and dev console to make sure that you're going to the correct URL.

Comment: BTW, the login page is /WEB-INF/login.jsp, and it's called from index.jsp (that is the page located in the root dir of the Web application).

Comment: Yes, I restart completely the tomcat7 container and error continues to happen. The thing is really anoying me is the reason why the application is looking for /WebApp/Login (I don't declare this in none part of the code, and I really look for it).